# CakePHP Variable containing an array of models becomes inaccessible?

Tags: php, json, cakephp

So I'm building this small REST API for a part of a website so I can load comments asynchronously, after the main content has loaded. But every time my dataset goes above 25 entries the variable where I store the comments becomes completely inaccessible.

This is exactly the database find operation I'm doing:

```
// A nice default before responding
$response = array('status'=>'error','message'=>'Request incomplete');
// [...] Some validation stuff

// $response is perfectly accessible here
$response = $this->Comment->find(
    'threaded',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Comment.object_class' => $query['object_class'],
            'Comment.object_id' => $query['object_id'] ,
            'Comment.status' => 'approved'
            ),
        'order' => 'Comment.created ASC'
        // No limits, I need all the comments
        )
    );
// $response is not accessible anymore
// So my JSON response below comes absolutely empty;
$this->set('response',$response);
$this->set('_serialize',array('response'));
```

By the time I use `$this->set('_serialize',array('response'));` to be able to send the JSON response the $comments variable is still inaccessible, so my response comes back empty, at 0 length, which of course is pretty bothersome and very confusing.

I've experienced this problem before and have found that it solves by requesting a limited set of entries, but in this case I need the entire comment list, don't wanna do several requests and kill the purpose. Is there a limit to what Cake can retrieve from the database and keep usable in the Controllers? Am I missing something here?

I also tried "manually " doing a `json_encode($response);` but since the problem is that the `$response` var is inaccessible/empty then of course it fails as well.

The json response does work for some 25 comments or less, but many of the website entries have more comments than that, up to 100 comments! How can I solve this weird issue?

Comment: How many entries are there in $response, I mean your estimation?

Comment: Data retrieval fails at around 25 or 30 root entries, I was also doing it as find('threaded'), because the comment thread also supports one nested level of comments. So I'd say around 30 entries it stops working.

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with query because 30 entries are like nothing, check table index's, set debug level 3 and get the actual query and run explain see what what is wrong in the query

Comment: Have you tried using debug($response), what does it show, do you get complete empty or it is also possible that it has data and indexing  has not done well, the variable with index ex $response[0]['Comment'].

Comment: So if I disable $belongsTo in the Comment Model I can make it work up to 50 entries, but this is actually not an option for me right now, since I don't save the user data to the comments themselves. When I use debug(); on a good dataset it shows what it should, but if I use it on the same var when it fails then nothing pops up, just the debugging box header and no content, it doesn't even say null.

Comment: Btw, the `$query` variable I use there is nothing to worry about, it is properly validated.

Comment: `debug($response[0]);` does work even if the complete array is not accessible, why could this happen? :o

Comment: `debug(count($response));` also gives the correct answer. This is so weird, I'll see if iterating over it by index (very sub-optimal workaround) gives me my results back!

Comment: So it turns out I ca iterate through the array, but not access it directly, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after souting the Internet in search of a concrete answer and ending up in the #cakephp IRC channel, a very kind fellow suggested my data may have some encoding mistakes.

Turns out he was correct about it, and the comments table still had some comments that were encoded as latin1. Back in the day I moved the database to utf8, but it was just a charset change, not an actual text encoding conversion for every entry.

After a quick search I found [this post](https://www.bluebox.net/insight/blog-article/getting-out-of-mysql-character-set-hell) which instructs you about how to move loads of data from latin1 to utf8 with three simple cli lines.

I hope this serves someone else that may encouter this issue and doesn't know what to do about it :)

Thanks to those who commented on the question.